# Conversion failed from VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use SQL to get new policy number based on the existing one. I don't want to use update since I don't want to permanently change the records.

My policy numbers are like **PFA991228-01** and I want to use SQL to modify and get **PFA991228-02**. So I am just updating the last 2 digits from 00 to 01 or from 05 to 06 etc. Right now I am getting error for converting varchar to int.

I am new to SQL so not sure if I can just achieve it in my first select statement instead of using sub-query

```
select 
left(p.policynum, 9) 
+ '-' 
+ right('00' + convert(varchar(255), right(p.policynum, 2) + 1), 2) as newPolicy
From Company55.dbo.policy p
where p.policynum not like '%S%'
```

Comment: Try executing just your SubSelect, and see if there are any values for 'Term' that could not be converted to INT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this logic:

```
select (left(p.policynum, 9) + '-' +
        right( '00' + try_convert(int, right(p.policynum, 2)) + 1 as varchar(255)), 2) as newPolicy
From Company55.dbo.policy P 
where p.policynum not like '%S%' and
      p.policynum like '%[0-9][0-9]';
```

Notes:

- The `where` ensures that the output rows all end in two digits.
- The `try_convert()` ensures that the conversion to integer succeeds -- the `where` is not enough.
- This works for both 1- and 2- digit suffixes.
- I see no reason for the subquery.  `right(p.policynum, 2)` isn't really that much more complicated than `term`, for instance.

Comment: Potential add...this logic depends on the policy number to be 9 digits long.  If they are longer/shorter, you will want to use patindex to detect where the '-' is and then use left from that. (left(p.policynum, patindex(p.policynum,'-') - 1)     ...I think that's right...my brackets might be off.

Comment: Thanks I used yours to modify my current codes and got the desire results.